# Strange results with javascript array.length function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have piece of JavaScript code which cycles through form elements and builds an object.
I have a mixture of HTML input fields and ASP.NET input fields. ASP.NET changes the ID of the fields to the form xxxxx_yyyy_id, so I am attempting to use the split function to extract the original id.

```
 // Iterate over all the text fields and build an object
 $(':text').each(function () {

     var tokens = this.id.split("_");
     if (tokens.length = 3) {
         // Assume this is a .net inputbox - extract the original id
         inFormData[tokens[2]] = this.value;
     } else {             
         inFormData[this.id] = this.value;
     }
 });
```

Stepping through the above code, the first id is ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCol1_forenameField, so the tokens.length = 3 code is run.
On the second iteration, the id is forenameField2 so I would expect the tokens.length to be 1, but it is actually 3. The else statement is never run.

This could be something simple, but I cant work it out. If I inspect the tokens array it has only 1 element in on the second iteration. I have also tried setting the array.length to 0 after each iteration.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `=` is assignment - you mean `==` (or even better `===`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct this:

```
== instead of =. === is more better


     if (tokens.length == 3) {
         // Assume this is a .net inputbox - extract the original id
         inFormData[tokens[2]] = this.value;
     } else {             
         inFormData[this.id] = this.value;
     }
```

Comment: Some people advice to use the constant at the left `(3 == tokens.length)`, because if you forget a `=` it becomes a compilation error. I don't like it, but it's got a point.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `= 3` to `=== 3`

At the moment you're overwriting `tokens.length` every time.

NB: `===` is preferred to `==` because it's an *exact* equality check.  The two-equals version will attempt to cast the two operands to the same type before comparison, which is 1. unnecessary, 2. inefficient, 3. sometimes error prone.

Answer (score 2):

That is why you should always put the constant first when testing. If you forget a comparison sign it will throw an error:

```
if( 3 = tokens.length ) // throws an error
if( 3 == tokens.length ) // ok
if( 3 === tokens.length) // ok
```

Answer (score 1):

from:

```
if (tokens.length = 3) {
```

to:

```
if (tokens.length == 3) {
```